Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1}subsystem'
Using JBPM version-7.74 and the wildfly version is 23.2, Trying to install keycloak getting below error.

OPVDX001: Validation error in standalone-full.xml 566:  567:  568:  Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1}subsystem' 569:  570: demo

Steps tried as per below article:
https://blog.kie.org/2016/03/keycloak-sso-integration-into-jbpm-and-drools-workbench.html

Those instructions are 8 years old - things have changed dramatically since then.  I don't have an updated version but that one is highly unlikely to work.

Could you please suggest if you have a working versions
